# Wrong distance between draggable and DragOverlay after list update

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I am experimenting with dnd-kit to apply drag and drop on a list that gets updated when the list item starts to be dragged.

Here is the original list:

[image]

and here is how it looks like after the dragging starts:

[image]

The list is updated correctly but it seems that the "original distance" between the dragged item and the DragOverlay is kept and not updated based on the new list height.

Even when the cursor with the dragged item is directly on the list, this distance is kept:

[image]

The expected behaviour is to have the draggable item area as close as possible to the DragOverlay:
[image]

I would appreciate your help!